# openURL and open in IOS 9 / 10

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, ios10, uiapplication

```
-UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
-UIApplicartion.shared.open(url,options: [:],completionHandler: nil)
```

Can I use these two options in iOS9 and iOS10?

Is `UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)` supported in iOS9 and/or iOS10?

Comment: please write proper question with your description.

Comment: look at this : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622961-openurl

Comment: It's deprecated, doesn't means it's removed. So yes you can still use it in iOS 10.

Answer (score 8):

You can try this

```
guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com") else {
  return //be safe
}

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

Comment: Actually you can use just `UIApplication.shared.open(url)` on iOS 10. The `options` and `completionHandler` already have these default parameters.

Comment: @petrsyn yes that correct, I will update my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Yes you have to use both by putting them in condition like this,

```
func open(scheme: String) {
  if let url = URL(string: scheme) {
    if #available(iOS 10, *) { // For ios 10 and greater
      UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:],
        completionHandler: {
          (success) in
           print("Open \(scheme): \(success)")
       })
    } else { // for below ios 10.
      let success = UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
      print("Open \(scheme): \(success)")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/") else { return }
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
            present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

I used this when I want to Open a URL in Safari browser in iOS 9 and above.